# Display tweets retrieved from database after onclick function

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

I am using JavaScript, PHP and HTML for my application. I have a SQL database that contains tweets. I need to query from database and display tweets after the keyword (connecting to a hyper tree) is clicked. I have researched and tried to include an external php file (generatetweets.php) inside myFunction() at index.php. However it's not working. Anyone can enlighten me or any reference for me to guide?
Thank you in advance.

Extracted example2.js, where child.name refers to the keyword from hyper tree

```
onComplete: function(){
        //Log.write("done");

        //Make the relations list shown in the right column.
        //ONCLICK FUNCTION FOR KEYWORDS TO LOAD RELATED TWEETS
        var node = ht.graph.getClosestNodeToOrigin("current");
        var html = "<div><b>Keyword: " + node.name + "</b></div>";
        html += "<ul>";
        node.eachAdjacency(function(adj){
            var child = adj.nodeTo;
            var childName=child.name;
            html += '<a onClick="myFunction('+'&#39;'+child.name+'&#39;'+')"><li>'+child.name + '</li></a>';

        });
        html += "</ul><br />";
        $jit.id('inner-details').innerHTML = html;
    }
```

generatetweets.php

```
<?php
// connect to the database
include "mysqli.connect.php";

// create your SQL statment to retrieve everything from
// the users table
$sql = "SELECT * FROM post WHERE content LIKE '%school%' ORDER BY date DESC";

// run the query
$result = $mysqli->query($sql);

// check for error
if ($mysqli->errno)
{
  error_log($mysqli->error);
  echo "<br />Something's wrong";
  exit();
}


?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <?php
        // Check if there are records in the first place
            if ($result->num_rows < 1)
                {
                    echo "<h3>No records found</h3>";
                }


            // Iterate through the records
            $counter = 0;
            // Use fetch_array to get rows returned one at a time
            while($row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC))
                {
    ?>  
                <table>
                    <tr id="tweetlist">
                        <td style="width:50px">
                            <!-- name goes here -->
                            <!--<img id="img<?=$counter?>" style="padding-right:5px" src="<?=$row["displaypicture"]?>"></img>-->

                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <!-- email textfield goes here -->
                            <span id="date<?=$counter?>" style="color:#CCFF33">[<?=$row["date"]?>] </span>
                            <span id="name<?=$counter?>">@<?=$row["username"]?>: </span>
                            <span id="emailTxt<?=$counter?>"><?=$row["content"]?> <span/>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
                <br/>
                <?php
                    $counter++;
                }
                    $result->free();
                    $mysqli->close();
                ?>

</body>
```

Extracted index.php, to display tweets in div "demo"

```
<body onload="init();">

<!-- Header -->
<div id="header" class="container">

    <!-- Logo -->
    <h1 id="logo"><a href="index.php">Mood</a></h1>  <!-- logo from style-n1.css -->

    <div id="center-container">
        <div id="infovis"></div>    
    </div>

    <div id="right-container">
        <div id="inner-details"></div>
        <div id="log"></div>
        <div id="node_name"></div>  
        <div id="demo" style="padding-left: 50px">

            <script type="text/javascript">
                function myFunction() {

                    $("#demo").load("generatetweets.php");  

                }
            </script>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

</body>
```

Hypertree is referenced from http://philogb.github.io/jit/static/v20/Jit/Examples/Hypertree/example2.html

Answer (score 0):

```
I obtained tweets using nodejs and append it to div. Here is my code. 
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>  
</head>

<body>

    <form>
     #<input type="text" id="tag" class="hash"/>
     <button>submit</button>
 </form>
 <div id="tweets"></div>

 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.js"></script>
 <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
 <script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"> </script>
 <script>
 var socket = io.connect("link to nodejs");
 var link;
 var tag;
 var a;

 function debounce(func, wait, immediate){

    var timeout;
    return function(){

        clearTimeout(timeout);

        timeout = setTimeout(function() {
            timeout = null;
            if (!immediate) func.apply();
        }, wait);
        if (immediate && !timeout) func.apply();
    };
};

var func = debounce(function(){
    $('#tweet').html("");
    socket.emit('message', $('#tag').val());
    tag=$('#tag').val();
    link="http://twitter.com/hashtag/"+tag;
    a="<a href="+'link'+" target='_blank'> #"+tag+"</a>";
},1000);

$('.hash').keypress(func);

$('.hash').on('change',function(){
    $('#tweet').html("");
    socket.emit('message', $('#tag').val());
    tag=$('#tag').val();
    link="http://twitter.com/hashtag/"+tag;
    a="<a href="+'link'+" target='_blank'> #"+tag+"</a>";
});



socket.on('message', function(msg){
    console.log(msg.length);

    $('#tag').val('');
    var regex = /(https?:\/\/([-\w\.]+)+(:\d+)?(\/([\w\/_\.]*(\?\S+)?)?)?)/ig ;
    var hashregex= /(#[a-z0-9][a-z0-9\-_]*)/ig;
    console.log(link);

    for(var i = 0; i < msg.length; i++){
        msg[i].tweettext=msg[i].tweettext.replace(hashregex,a);
        msg[i].tweettext=msg[i].tweettext.replace(regex, "<a href='$1' target='_blank'>$1</a>");

        $('#tweets').after('<div>UserName: ' + msg[i].username+ '</div>');
        $('#tweets').after('<div>Text: ' + msg[i].tweettext+ '</div>');   
        $('#tweets').after('<div>Time: ' + msg[i].timedate+ '</div>');
        $('#tweets').after('<br></br>');
    }
});

</script>

</body>
<html>
```

Comment: Hi thank you for the reply. I can retrieve tweets and insert it into mysql database. But now, when I click the keyword, I would like it to retrieve the keywords's tweets from mysql database again. So how can I enhance my code to do it? Thank you.